# Typescript - Accessing value from enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I was trying to solve a typescript challenge and encountered this issue `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.` on this line `Resistors[val]` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If anyone could direct me here, that'd be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
enum Resistors {
  Black = 0,
  Brown = 1,
  Red = 2,
  Orange = 3,
  Yellow = 4,
  Green = 5,
  Blue = 6,
  Violet = 7,
  Grey = 8,
  White = 9
} 

export function decodedValue(labels : string[]) {
  let valuesArr: string[] = labels.map((value: string) => {
    const val: string = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
     return Resistors[val];
  });
  return Number(valuesArr.join(''));
}

console.log(decodedValue(['brown', 'black']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Enum should look like this ([source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums)):

```js
enum Resistors {
  Black,
  Brown,
  Red,
  Orange,
  Yellow,
  Green,
  Blue,
  Violet,
  Grey,
  White,
}
```

Second of all, here is the [source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time) on how to access an Enum's property.

Then, something like this would work:

```js
export function decodedValue(labels: string[]) {
  let valuesArr: number[] = labels.map((value: string) => {
    const val: string = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    return Resistors[val as keyof typeof Resistors];
  });
  return Number(valuesArr.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that you're trying to access the enum with an arbitrary string. The value of `val` has to be one of the `Resistor` colors.

```js
enum Resistors {
  Black = 0,
  Brown = 1,
  Red = 2,
  Orange = 3,
  Yellow = 4,
  Green = 5,
  Blue = 6,
  Violet = 7,
  Grey = 8,
  White = 9
} 

 function decodedValue(labels : string[]) {
  let valuesArr: string[] = labels.map((value: string) => {
    const val: Resistors = (value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)) as unknown as Resistors;
    return Resistors[val];
  });
  return Number(valuesArr.join(''));
}

console.log(decodedValue(['brown', 'black']));
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way than `as unknown as Resistors`.